# Objective-C: Share object between two view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iPhone application and I do this in my `MyView1Controller`:

```
MyView2Controller *myV2C = [[MyView2Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView2" bundle:nil];
myV2C.shareObject = self.shareObject;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myV2C animated:YES];
[myV2C release];
```

So I push `shareObject` to the next ViewController. There, in `viewDidLoad`, I set a property of `shareObject` like this:

```
self.shareObject.myText = @"Test String";
```

So in MyView2Controller, everything is okay, the String is set. But going back to the previous `MyView1Controller` with the left upper "back" Button, the value of `shareObject.myText` is not set to `Test String`.

So, how can I do this? I want to give the View2Controller an object which can be modified, and the modifications I want to have in the View1Controller.

Does anyone know? Thank you in advance & Best Regards, Tim.

Comment: Have you already tried using Singleton/shared object? http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SingletonDesignPattern

Comment: You did it right already, so there must be something wrong somewhere. Could you also post more code, like the code of `shareObject`?

Comment: Yep, it would help to see the property declaration of shareObject (in both classes), and the getters/setters (if you didn't just @synthesize them).

Comment: You are right, it was my fault: If I modify the `shareObject` in `myV2C`, it is there in `myV1C`, so the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tia was right: "You did it right already, so there must be something wrong somewhere".
It was my fault, so the source code in my question is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegation pattern and/or key value observations

EDIT:
 You can achieve this my creating a single object, and then use that object in all classes, wherever you want. For this you can use singleton class, Or you can create a class method. For ex:If I have class A, and I want to push some values in B class, So if I modify the values in B, the newly updated value can be retrieved in a too, or in any other class. In that case, you can create a different class (usually subclass of NSObject),and then write the getter/settor methods in that.

Suppose the name of this newly created class is Manager, then in Manager. m create getter/setter methods, like

```
NSString *strGlobal;
+(void)setString:(NSString *)strTemp
{
if(!strGlobal)
{
    strGlobal = [[NSString alloc] init];
}

//point to same location
strGlobal = strTemp;
}

+(NSString *)getMySavedString
{
    return strGlobal;
}
```

Now In you class A , where you want to send the value to Class B controller, call the setter method to set the value, like: -

```
-(void)navigateto_ClassB
{
         //Setting the value, that should be sent to the other controller
     [ManagerClass setString:@"Hello"];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[[ClassB alloc]init] autorelease] animated:YES];
}
```

Now In class B (Or wherever you want to get the saved value, use getter method, like:-

```
     NSString *strSavedValue = [ManagerClass getMySavedString];
```

No you will have the value, If you want to update the value from anywhere, the again call the setter method, with new value. For ex, i want to update the value in class B, then

```
 [ManagerClass setString:@"Hello Upadted"];
```

Now this value is updated to same memory location, retrieve it from anywhere using getter method created in Manager class.

As I stated earlier, this is the easiest but not the best approach. Alternatively, you can achieve same functionality with delegate patterns, KVOs (Key value observations) and/or singleton class.

Comment: Is it not possible to set a pointer, so there is one instance I can modify?

Answer (score 1):

OR you can even try using the Singleton pattern

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SingletonDesignPattern

Comment: Hm, but it is not really a singleton in my case.